# Hide Toolbar with CoordinationLayout and Webview not working

Tags: android, webview, toolbar

I'm trying to hide the Toolbar when scrolling the WebView, with the new CordinationLayout, but it's not working. Is there any way to do it?
This is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.themobilebakery.isus.gui.WebViewActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/webview_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/webview_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/isus_orange_progres_webview"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554824/how-to-reset-the-toolbar-position-controlled-by-the-coordinatorlayout

Comment: Maybe putting the `WebView` under the `AppBarLayout`, then putting the `WebView` in a `NestedScrollLayout` helps? Not sure.

Comment: I try to use before the NestedScrollLayout,  but always getting:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView , how do you use it?

Comment: can you please post the solution?

Comment: the solution is answered below, only change the webview in my code with the answer code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add layout_behavior in webview

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: No, sorry I miss to pout in the xml, I change now

Comment: try my updated code. put your webview in NestedScrollView

Comment: I am puting com. before the nested ScrollView, thats my error, thanks