# Add views below toolbar in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, androiddesignsupport

I have the following layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I add `Fragment`s into the `FrameLayout`, replacing them. One of my `Fragment`s is a list, which has the following layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

My problem here that the **toolbar is drawn over the list**. I tried to solve that by wrapping the content of the `CoordinatorLayout` into a `LinearLayout`, that solved the overdraw, but that way the appbar scrolling behavior no longer work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 386, accepted):

Take the attribute

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

off the `RecyclerView` and put it on the `FrameLayout` that you are trying to show under the `Toolbar`.

I've found that one important thing the scrolling view behavior does is to layout the component below the toolbar.  Because the `FrameLayout` has a descendant that will scroll (`RecyclerView`), the `CoordinatorLayout` will get those scrolling events for moving the `Toolbar`.

---

One other thing to be aware of:  That layout behavior will cause the `FrameLayout` height to be sized *as if the `Toolbar` is already scrolled*, and with the `Toolbar` fully displayed the entire view is simply pushed down so that the bottom of the view is below the bottom of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

This was a surprise to me.  I was expecting the view to be dynamically resized as the toolbar is scrolled up and down.  So if you have a scrolling component with a fixed component at the bottom of your view, you won't see that bottom component until you have fully scrolled the `Toolbar`.

So when I wanted to anchor a button at the bottom of the UI, I worked around this by putting the button at the bottom of the `CoordinatorLayout` (`android:layout_gravity="bottom"`) and adding a bottom margin equal to the button's height to the view beneath the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks very much, this really works! My only problem after that if the toolbar was moved out, it did not return after replacing the `Fragment` containing with a list with another `Fragment`. I managed to manually show the toolbar [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30729413/747412) way.

Comment: Having the layout of the view coupled with the scrolling behavior is a problem if you want to expand/collapse the app bar programmatically without any scroll event.

Answer (score 95):

I managed to fix this by adding:

> android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

to the FrameLayout like so:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
```

Comment: Instead of adding marginTop add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: Perfect solution when @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is not available

Comment: Please use `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: This is kinda hacky, adding a margin of what the size MIGHT be (assuming you will always have a toolbar that size) is going to break at some point

Comment: It will definitely break if you use a CollapsingToolbarLayout, the height will not be constant in that case

Answer (score 3):

To use collapsing top ToolBar or using ScrollFlags of your own choice
we can do this way:[From Material Design](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/#:~:text=To%20add%20a%20collapsing%20toolbar,a%20child%20to%20the%20CollapsingToolbarLayout%20.) get rid of FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="back"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/post_details_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Android studio 3.4, You need to put this line in your Layout which holds the `RecyclerView`.

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at it. Try giving margin of the same size as that of toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/constraintLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```