# How to implement MiniDrawer using mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

I am trying to implement MiniDrawer using [mikepenz/MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) github library. I could get some result as below picture. but the top part of MiniDrawer is hidden by Toolbar. How can i solve this problem.

[image: Screenshot of the app]

This is MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Drawer result = null;
    private MiniDrawer miniResult = null;
    private Crossfader crossFader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withTranslucentNavigationBar(false)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_compact_header).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_wb_sunny).withIdentifier(1),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_action_bar_drawer).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withBadge("22").withBadgeStyle(new BadgeStyle(Color.RED, Color.RED)).withIdentifier(2).withSelectable(false),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_multi_drawer).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_gamepad).withIdentifier(3),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_non_translucent_status_drawer).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_eye).withIdentifier(4),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withDescription("A more complex sample").withName(R.string.drawer_item_advanced_drawer).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_adb).withIdentifier(5),
                        new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_section_header),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_open_source).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_github),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_contact).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_format_color_fill).withTag("Bullhorn"),
                        new DividerDrawerItem(),
                        new SwitchDrawerItem().withName("Switch").withIcon(Octicons.Icon.oct_tools).withChecked(true).withOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener),
                        new ToggleDrawerItem().withName("Toggle").withIcon(Octicons.Icon.oct_tools).withChecked(true).withOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener)
                ) // add the items we want to use with our Drawer
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        if (drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((Nameable) drawerItem).getName().getText(MainActivity.this), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withGenerateMiniDrawer(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .buildView();

        miniResult = result.getMiniDrawer();

        int firstWidth = (int) UIUtils.convertDpToPixel(300, this);
        int secondWidth = (int) UIUtils.convertDpToPixel(72, this);

        crossFader = new Crossfader()
                .withContent(findViewById(R.id.main_content))
                .withFirst(result.getSlider(), firstWidth)
                .withSecond(miniResult.build(this), secondWidth)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build();

        miniResult.withCrossFader(new CrossfadeWrapper(crossFader));

        //define a shadow (this is only for normal LTR layouts if you have a RTL app you need to define the other one
        crossFader.getCrossFadeSlidingPaneLayout().setShadowResourceLeft(R.drawable.material_drawer_shadow_left);
    }

    private OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(IDrawerItem drawerItem, CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
                Log.i("material-drawer", "DrawerItem: " + ((Nameable) drawerItem).getName() + " - toggleChecked: " + isChecked);
            } else {
                Log.i("material-drawer", "toggleChecked: " + isChecked);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //add the values which need to be saved from the drawer to the bundle
        outState = result.saveInstanceState(outState);
        //add the values which need to be saved from the crossFader to the bundle
        outState = crossFader.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //handle the back press :D close the drawer first and if the drawer is closed close the activity
        if (crossFader != null && crossFader.isCrossFaded()) {
            crossFader.crossFade();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_1)
                .setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, FontAwesome.Icon.faw_repeat)
                .color(Color.WHITE).actionBar());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_1:
                crossFader.crossFade();
                return true;
            case R.id.act_settings:
                return true;
            default:
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sldroids.minidrawer_v3.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

@sendtodilanka the problem is that you add the `Crosssfader` as the parent of the `main_content` view, which is a direct child of your `CoordinatorLayout`.

As the `CoordinatorLayout` is similar to the `FrameLayout` and does overlap views your `Crossfader` will simply be displayed below the `AppBarLayout` which you have defined to be over the `main_content`.

To get the `Crossfader` below the `Toolbar` you should add a new `View` around your `main_content`, let's choose a `FrameLayout` which has the attribute (don't forget to define the `appBarLayout` id to your `AppBarLayout`)
`xml
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

After this the `Crossfader` will get inflated as a child of the `FrameLayout` we added above, which is displayed below the `AppBarLayout`.

A more detailed information regarding this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32959820/325479).

---

So your layout will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sldroids.minidrawer_v3.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried as your answer to solve my problem.. but it is not yet solve.. Also I replied you answer about the what i do and the result. please go through [this link](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/1429)