# AppBarLayout is not on the top of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-appbarlayout

My issue is, that AppBarLayout, together with toolbar is appearing not on top of the screen, thus blocking the view of the included content. It can be seen in the image. I am sure I am just missing something here.

[image]

Also, here is the xml code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_search" />
```

EDIT: with my theme set to NoActionBar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't care about the default toolbar shown at the top in preview window if you have set the **style** to **NoActionBar**  as the preview assumes to have default toolbar to be the actual toolbar in the application. It will not be present on the deployed app

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal default toolbar doesnt show up in the deployed app, you are right, but the thing is that the custom toolbar blocks the view of the included content.

Comment: try setting ``android:fitSystemWindows``

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal it is set to true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `res/values/styles` set your style to `NoActionBar` theme, like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Now, you should lose your regular ActionBar and you can work with your toolbar.

EDIT: What OP tried to acomplish was position included layout below `AppBar` layout in `CoordinatorLayout`. That's accomplished by adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to include layout.

Comment: Hey. I edited the main post. This didnt completely help me.

Comment: How it didn't help? AppBar is now on top of the screen, right below status bar. If you want to hide status bar also, use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen `

Comment: Apparently, there is no standard fullscreen AppCompat theme (although Holo had this). You can refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/4110778

Comment: It is on top of the screen, but it is still blocking the view of included searchview. After the app toolbar is on the top, but the searchview is underneath it.

Comment: Oh OK then. So, your root layout: CoordinatorLayout is like FrameLayout - meaning it stacks views one on another. You should add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to root of your included layout, so it shows it bellow toolbar. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956071/add-views-below-toolbar-in-coordinatorlayout

Comment: Thank you! Fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout_width and layout_height to match parent for the include layout(The layout that is inside the include layout).